# Does feature order impact Decision tree algorithm in sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I read some material:

- [decision tree document in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier)
- [A Quora Answer](https://www.quora.com/In-a-decision-tree-how-do-we-select-which-attribute-to-split-the-data-by-at-each-level)

However I can find if I change feature order(the set of feature name:
 [a,b,c] change into [b,a,c]) in the data. Does this actually affect decision tree result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Sklearn generally uses Cart trees where the best split is decided by picking the feature that minimizes a cost function. So the order of column doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thank you, I have a question. If the data is so large(Maybe [10^6, 10^5]). In the first time,  I have to compute all the feature's best splitter. That maybe  O(n^2). This is very slowly. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, a single CART decision tree will need to scan trough all the data and all the features to find the best split. Usually you wouldn’t code a tree yourself, since there are many optimised libraries that do that job for you pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Reordering column names **can** change `sklearn` decision tree result. The issue is that for each split, `max_features` are considered and the feature with highest impact (e.g. largest gini reduction) is chosen.

However, if multiple features have the same impact -- this is not as uncommon as might seem especially with a high number of binary features -- one of them is chosen randomly.

In such a case, order of columns in your dataset may impact what feature is selected in the final decision tree. To make sure you prevent this, it is necessary to both choose `random seed` and to sort your dataframe columns before fitting your tree.

More explanations can be found [here (engelen's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391429/classification-tree-in-sklearn-giving-inconsistent-answers) and in this [Github discussion](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5394).