# what decision tree in matlab takes account on the features' order?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

why is it when we use fictree for the same training matrix (**same features**) but with different order, we do not get the same model and thus not the same error of classification ?
example:

if we have x1,x2,x3 as predictor, training matrix M1=[x1,x2,x3] or M2=[x2,x1,x3] and fitctree(M1,Label), fitctree(M2,Label) will not have the same model. why?

Comment: You need to show a [mcve]

Comment: you can see the example posted below

Comment: Nope I cant, Post code in Stackoverflow and for heavens shake, not as images.

Comment: Deleted my answer because it was completely wrong - the tree is actually deterministic, only the cross validation isn't. So the seed has no effect on the tree. Sry for wasting your time. But i'm *very* curious what the cause is, because from a logical standpoint it makes no sense to me. `fitctree` uses CART which always takes the feature that increases the impurity the most. Also, in other languages the order apparently does NOT play a role even tough they also use CART, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43941163/does-feature-order-impact-decision-tree-algorithm-in-sklearn

Comment: ok thank you for your answer :) no problem